# In autolayout, how can I have view take up half of the screen, regardless of orientation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

In portrait mode, I have a tableview on the left-side, and a webview on the right-side. They both take half of the screen. I have autolayout enabled.

But when I rotate the screen to landscape mode, the tableview's width takes up less than half the screen's size, and the webview ends up taking more, instead of them being an even split.

Why does this happen? How can I have the views take up only half the screen in regard to their widths, regardless of screen orientation?

Comment: Related: [How can I rearrange views when autorotating with autolayout?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30515009/2792531)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The first half of the answer address the case in which we want to split the view evenly between view A (blue) and view B (red).  The second half will address the case in which we want to have view A take up half the screen, but view B does not exist.

## Step 1:

[image]

Set up blue's auto-layout constraints as pictured.  Top, left, bottom of 0 to the superview.  Right of 0 to the red view.

## Step 2:

[image]

Set up the same, but mirrored, constraints for the red view.

If you've completed the first two steps correctly, you should have some auto-layout errors and warnings:

[image]

We need one more constraint to fix these errors/warnings and get what we need.

## Step 3:

[image]

Hold control, click and drag from one view to the other and select "equal widths".  Now our views will always maintain the same width.  All of our auto layout warnings and errors disappear, and our views will always be half the screen no matter the orientation or device.

To add these constraints in code using VFL, we need the following constraints:

```
@"H:|[blueView(==redView)][redView]|"
@"V:|[blueView]|"
@"V:|[redView]|"
```

---

Now, suppose the case where we want a single view to take up half the screen, but we don't have a view for the other half.  We can still do this with auto layout, but it's a slightly different set up.  In this example, our view is blue, and its parent view is green.

## Step 1:

[image]

This is similar to step 1 above, except we don't add a right side constraint (this will obviously vary if we want our view to take up a different half).

## Step 2:

[image]

Like before, we want to assign an "equal widths" constraint.  In this case, from our view to the parent view.  Again, hold control and click drag from one to the other.

[image]

At this point, we have an auto layout warning.  Auto layout wants our frame to match its parent's width.  Clicking the warning and choosing "Update constraints" will put a hardcoded value in.  We don't want this.

## Step 3:

[image]

Select the view and go to its size inspector.  Here, we'll be able to edit the constraints.

Click "Edit" next to the "Equal Width to:" constraint.  We need to change the multiplier value.

[image]

We need to change the multiplier value to 2.

The constraint now changes to a "Proportional Width to:", and all of our auto layout warnings and errors disappear.  Now our view will always take up exactly half of the super view.

To add these constraints in code, we can add some using VFL:

```
@"H:|[blueView]"
@"V:|[blueView]|"
```

But the proportional width constraint can't be added with VFL.  We must add it as such:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *constraint =
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:blueView
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth 
                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                    toItem:superView
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                multiplier:2.0
                                  constant:0.0];
```

Comment: Amazing answer, I love the effort you put into it. Now that I know about equal widths, would you know how to set it programmatically?

Would this work? @"[leftView][rightView][leftView(==rightView)]"

Comment: To set an equal widths constraint with VFL is as simple as `@"[leftView(==rightView)]"`.  But you'd also want the other constraints.  So you'd want:  `@"|[leftView(==rightView)][rightView]|"` (and you'd still need the vertical constraint)

Comment: (Also remember you can change the accepted answer.)

Comment: That gives me equal widths of both views, but stacked on top of each other, instead of side by side like the original. Is that what you meant by the vertical constraint?

Comment: Put an `H:` in front of that string.  So you want to create these constraints: `@"H:|[leftView(==rightView)][rightView]|"` for the horizontal, and for the vertical you want to create: `@"V:|[leftView]|"` and `@"V:|[rightView]|"`

Comment: Great. I was looking for the second scenario. On thing didn't work for me though. I had to set the multiplier to 0.5 instead of 2. IB kept wanting the width of my half-view to be twice the width of the parent view. Changing to 0.5 got me the expected results.

Comment: Great answer. But the same layout does not work in Xcode 8. Does someone has any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Excellent solution, I am using the "Multiplier" == 2 to implement my request. thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Create a `UIView` in `XIB` or `Storyboard`

1. Set top and left constraints
2. Set a height constraint
3. Set width constraint to equal width of the super view ***Important**
4. Edit the width of the constraint by converting it to decimal

[image]

5. Set the decimal to the width you'd like (In my case 0.5 or half)

**[image: Result]**

Answer (score 4):

Bind both of them to the superview edges (table view to the leading edge, web view to the trailing edge) and set constraint for them to have same width.

Comment: You would also need a horizontal spacing constraint between the table view and web view.

Comment: So, right now in portrait mode, they both have a width of 384. Just give them both a width constraint with this current value?

Comment: No. Select both of them and create constraint that would say 'Equal Width'. And as @rdelmar mentioned - make sure you have constraint between right edge of table view and left edge of web view

Comment: I think I have a horizontal spacing constraint between the two views, I have also set their width constraints. But in landscape mode, the tableview takes two-thirds of the screen.

Comment: Remove any constraints that specify hardcoded width

Answer (score 4):

Programatically in Swift 4:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let halfScreenViewLeft: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .blue
        return view
    }()

    let halfScreenViewRight: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        return view
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(halfScreenViewLeft)
        view.addSubview(halfScreenViewRight)

        //Enable Autolayout
        halfScreenViewLeft.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        //Place the top side of the view to the top of the screen
        halfScreenViewLeft.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true

        //Place the left side of the view to the left of the screen.
        halfScreenViewLeft.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true

        //Set the width of the view. The multiplier indicates that it should be half of the screen.
        halfScreenViewLeft.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true

        //Set the same height as the view´s height
        halfScreenViewLeft.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor).isActive = true

        //We do the same for the right view

        //Enable Autolayout
        halfScreenViewRight.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        //Place the top side of the view to the top of the screen
        halfScreenViewRight.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true

        //The left position of the right view depends on the position of the right side of the left view

        halfScreenViewRight.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: halfScreenViewLeft.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

        //Place the right side of the view to the right of the screen.
        halfScreenViewRight.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

        //Set the same height as the view´s height
        halfScreenViewRight.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor).isActive = true


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The constraint system can't read your mind. You must say what you want. Half is half. If you want half, say half. To make a view half the width of its superview, give it a width constraint that has a multiplier of `.5` in relation to its superview's width.

Comment: You could have left out your first 4 sentences, the last one is where you actually gave the useful information.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I use with the useful information. "Give it a width constraint that has a multiplier of .5 in relation to its superview's width."

Comment: Yup this is great answer ...exactly what I was looking for. Unfortunate about the condescending tone.